# Is there a way control access to PyPI artifacts through LDAP Integration

Tags: python, pip, ldap, devops, pypi

Trying to implement this for a small group that has a PyPI server to host 3rd party and internal packages. The challenge is that they want to access control the internal artifacts and lock newer version to the package's developers only. Is there a way to enforce LDAP based access control to the PyPI server? I am considering Artifactory too but that's a longer term solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had a short look at [devpi-ldap](https://github.com/devpi/devpi-ldap):

- It strictly (stupidly) requires that your LDAP server returns the
  user's DN as an attribute in the user entry.
- It also does not escape special LDAP filter chars in user input making it prone to [LDAP injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/LDAP_injection).